# Why are all my objects distorted after editting scale?

Tags: 3d-view

I adjusted the scale of my models, now all objects look distorted. Clipping is set very low and high respectively. Is there an (easy) way to solve this?

It has to be something with the viewport itself; when i look through a camera (in the same - solid shaded - view) or in orthographic view, everything looks good.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These setting can cause that problem. Set them to the same values your camera uses.
[image: Near Far Settings]

Comment: Thanks a lot Josip, that worked! I already experimented with those settings, but setting them to the camera settings did it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man!......